# Limiting public access to azure storage blob

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage, symlink

I am creating a PHP application on azure.

I require users to have access to stream videos that will be stored in a storage blob for a limited period of time.

If I was using a Linux server I would so something like this.

- store video some place not publicly accessible.
- user requests video - create symbolic link to video that is accessible.
- do my logic to determine when accessing no longer allowed.
- remove symbolic link.

Is there the ability to achieve this with azure blob storage? I am unable to find documentation on symbolic links or similar.

Comment: You can't create symbolic links as it's not a file storage system.  Look at shared access signatures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements that you want to determine when accessing no longer allowed. You could [grant access from an internet IP range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range) then remove your client's IP address in the [Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security) when you don't allow it anymore.

[image]

Comment: Can this be added via PHP?

Comment: In theory, this is possible but I just find add the NetworkRuleSet with [using C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage.models.storageaccount?view=azure-dotnet.) Or you can try to do it via Azure powershell or cli from your PHP code.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The comment above re SAS works better.

Comment: Well, you can show your solution here for more references.